A 90’s thriller movie
I’m looking for a 90’s thriller movie, which is similar like I Know What You Did Last Summer (1997). I watched it in 2001, so the release date must be between 1995-2000. There were 4 college male friends. They were all white, young and Caucasian. They threw up parties, having fun, etc.. When the graduation date was coming, they decided to went a lake with one of theirs girlfriend. She was in relationship with the one who was at the drama class. 
When they were at the lakeside, the girl and one of students were separated from the group, took a walk and got in the car, which the vehicle of the girl’s boyfriend. The student wasn’t her boyfriend, he was one of the other students. They were flirting and suddenly they started to making love. Suddenly the gun at the glove-box was fired accidentally and it killed the girl. 
The others heard the sound and ran to the car. But it was too late, she was gone. They decided to bury the girl and disappear the car, because the car was stolen. Dead girl’s boyfriend, who was at drama class and also stole the car, handed over to bury her. 
After a while he somehow accused from car theft and got a 8 year prison sentence. The other 3 guys tried to forget this tragedy and moved on their lives. They got graduated, got married, had some kids, etc.. He payed his years and released from the prison after 8 years. He was mad and wanted to take revenge from his friends. I don’t remember how but he found his friends easily and threatened them to tell this to the authorities and did his dirty work against their will. 
I couldn’t remember the rest of it because I fell asleep. 
Some other details:
Orgin country: USA
Language: English 
Genre: Thriller 
Duration: 80 – 120 Mins

What We Did That Night (1999)

Henry (Schroder) is a manipulative ex-con who returns to his hometown with a proposition for three of his former college buddies, who have all become successful. They all share a secret—during a frat party hazing incident a young woman accidentally died and the foursome buried her body in an isolated area in the woods. Now Henry wants to develop that particular piece of property, so they have to go back and dig up the evidence of their crime.





Watched it and yeah that's the movie. Such a quick reply, thanks !!
